# Displaying a picture in an array form, dimensional error

Tags: python, image, pytorch

If you need any additional information, please let me know.
I am having a bug on the second like of following code.

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    img, label = self.data[index]
    return img, int(label)
```

I printed DONE every time this getitem method is ran. Below is the full error trace.

```
DONE
DONE
DONE
DONE
DONE
DONE
DONE
Traceback (most recent call last):
DONE
  File "selfsupervised_learning.py", line 178, in <module>
    main()
  File "selfsupervised_learning.py", line 169, in main
DONE
    loss_record = train(epoch, model, device, dloader_train, optimizer, exp_lr_scheduler, criterion, args)
  File "selfsupervised_learning.py", line 65, in train
    for batch_idx, (data, label) in enumerate(tqdm(dataloader(epoch))):
  File "/home/mchoi/anaconda3/envs/auto_novel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 1005, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/home/mchoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 435, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/mchoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1085, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/home/mchoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1111, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/home/mchoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 428, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
ValueError: Caught ValueError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mchoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 198, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/home/mchoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/mchoi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/mchoi/anaconda3/envs/auto_novel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchnet/dataset/listdataset.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self.load(self.list[idx])
  File "/data/mchoi/AutoNovel/data/rotationloader.py", line 205, in _load_function
    img0, _ = self.dataset[idx]
  File "/data/mchoi/AutoNovel/data/rotationloader.py", line 140, in __getitem__
    img, label = self.data[index]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

**What I found out:**
self.data[index] looks comes in 4 parts. one array of some numbers with ... in the middle, an array of all zeros, and huge array of arrays, and an integer. I looks like this: (array([0.48, 0.02, ...(actually has 3 dots in middle of an array, 0.14, 0. , 0.07 ]), [0,0,0,0....], [array([4.41, 4.43.....]),array([5.12, 4.48.....]), (more arrays)... ), 16).

self.data[index] should be turned into an image and a label. It seems like first three arrays are for each dimensions of an image and last integer is the label. When I run this code, I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. The weirdest part is that this method runs well for the first few times, but stops.

**What I tried:**
I first tried to skip some arrays by using `temp1, temp2, img, label = self.data[index]` but I got `TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'list'>` Only way the skipping method worked was when I used `img, skip1,skip2, label = self.data[index]`. Then now I got `ValueError: pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got 1 dimensions.` which means I need all three arrays in one variable "img". Is there a way to create ndarray with these three arrays?

**Shape of self.data[index]:**
I used following code to print shapes. part2 is a list of zeros, so I printed length, and part 4 is one integer.

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    part1, part2,part3, part4 = self.data[index]
    print("part 1 : " + str(part1.shape))
    print("part 2 : " + str(len(part2)))
    print("part 3 : " + str([t.shape for t in part3]))
    print("part 4 : " + str(part4))
    img, label = self.data[index]
    return img, int(label)
```

The result is

```
part 1 : (2048,)
part 2 : 150
part 3 : [(312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,), (312,)]
part 4 : 25
```

Comment: "*It seems like first three arrays*", you don't know? Where does this data come from, what's the shape of the tensors in parts **1**, **2**, and **3** of `self.data[index]`?

Comment: @Ivan Please refer to "What I found out" section. I described how they look like. I meant those arrays seem like first three arrays of the 3 dimensions.

Comment: You describe how they *look like* but I'm interested in their exact **shapes**, it will be far more relevant here to solve your issue.

Comment: @Ivan I edited the main post. The shapes are at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Where are you getting this data? Can you not refer to some kind of documentation?

Comment: @Ivan the data is "torch.utils.data" The documentations are at pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html. Can I use this utils if I am using ZSL datasets? The dataset is CUB.

Comment: Please describe the dataset you are using, this is at the core of your problem. You need to figure out what data you are dealing with.

Comment: @ Ivan CUB is a dataset for computer vision, especially for zero shot learning. It contains images of birds and labels(attributes). The detail can be found at http://www.vision.caltech.edu/visipedia/CUB-200-2011.html

Comment: As I said you are the one who should be looking into this, you **should** know what data you are dealing with, there shouldn't be any guessing here.

Comment: @Ivan my knowing the data, do you mean what shape, size, type of data I am receiving?

Comment: I meant this whole question is about understanding what `self.data[index]` is returning. If you had taken some time to read the documentation of the dataset you are using, you would know exactly what is what, *i.e.* what each array represents... This is not the case here, you are asking something you should figure out yourself. We can't help you if you haven't done this part of the work.

Comment: @Ivan If I want to talk about next problem I faced(solved the current one) Do I summarize and delete current post or do I just keep adding things at the bottom of the page?